# How to sort a list of class objects on one of its fields?

Tags: java, class, sorting, comparator

I have a list of DataPoint objects. The class definition is:

```
public static class DataPoint
     {
         public Comparable X;
         public Comparable Y;
         public Comparable Z;

         public String text; 

               ...
          }
```

"list" is an ArrayList of DataPoint objects. How do I sort list only on the X value? Would Collections.sort(list, comparator) be used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

- implement [`Comparable<DataPoint>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for your `DataPoint` class
- write a custom comparator that implements [`Comparator<DataPoint>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and then use `Collections.sort`

First solution is meaningful if you want to give a natural ordering on your objects (which will be the most used one). Usually it's the one you use first while you use comparators just when you need additional orderings.

They both behave in the same way but `Comparable<T>` is inherently attached to the object as it is its default comparison algorithm. Whenever sorting is involved the default one will be used unless you specify another one.

```
class DataPoint implements Comparable<DataPoint> {
  @Override
  public int compareTo(DataPoint o) {
    return X.compareTo(o.X);
  }
}
```

Mind that when you need to compare objects you usually need also other operations on them so take care of overriding `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)`. The latter is used in sorting as documentations states:

> The natural ordering for a class C is said to be consistent with equals if and only if e1.compareTo(e2) == 0 has the same boolean value as e1.equals(e2) for every e1 and e2 of class C. ... **It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals.**

**This means that if you just compare X variable then two different `DataPoint` objects with same `X` will be considered equal with respect to `compareTo`. This can lead to strange situations.**

Comment: yes I want to use natural ordering on the objects. Could you please tell me the syntax?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should create specific comparator for each field. Example:

```
Comparator<DataPoint> compByX = new Comparator<DataPoint>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(DataPoint left, DataPoint right) {
        return left.X.compareTo(right.X);
    }
};
Collections.sort(list, compByX);
```

Comment: Do you mean `left.X.compareTo(right.X);` or `left.Y.compareTo(right.Y);` ?